# What is the name of this town shown on the lock screen of Windows 10?

Tags: identify-this, lock-screens

I found these buildings on the lock screen of Windows 10:

[image: town view with many roofs.]

What's the name of this scenery ?

Comment: Pro tip for Windows 10 login screens. There's a spot in the upper right corner labelled something along "Like this picture?" depending on language, which you can mouse-over. And then they'll tell you where it was taken. You can even click on the label, log in and then get more info in a web browser.

Comment: @Lundin "Like this picture? spot is not showing up otherwise I wouldn't seek answer here.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/like-what-you-see-windows-10-spotlight

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a landscape of [Verucchio](https://www.google.com/maps?sca_esv=558689801&output=search&q=verucchio&source=lnms&entry=mc&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ1-jxqO2AAxVpXfEDHZpmBhcQ0pQJegQIDBAB), Rimini, (Emilia) Romagna, Italia

[image]

Comment: It's interesting that the slightly different viewpoint and different colour cast makes it look like a quite different place.  But the landmarks clearly match.

Comment: Microsoft's hard post-production! Look at the blue of the sky, the green of the trees in the background and the whiteness of the roofs, they can't be real!

Comment: Searching for this image finds its author and history: https://vividaphoto.com/verucchio-chosen-as-windows-spotlight-image/ , https://windows10spotlight.com/images/25530, https://christianaimago.com/stock-photo/roofs-of-ancient-village-1510/ , https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-roofs-of-ancient-village-in-romagna-italy-107175637.html , https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/roofs-ancient-village-romagna-italy-439422733 , https://stock.adobe.com/images/roofs-of-ancient-village/114103887 ...

Comment: @neil, *most* of the landmarks clearly match.  But the really distinctive bell tower in the foreground is missing from Microsoft's picture.

Comment: @Mark If anything, I'd say that Microsoft's picture was taken from just next to the bell tower. Perhaps from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XDXM.jpg) ?

Comment: Hell! You're going very deep in this question! I'd say that the picture I've found was taken from 43.98413463471246, 12.421985055433822. I can't locate the position of OP's picture as Google Maps satellite images are pretty old and in poor quality. I'll be around that spot soon, I'll have an inspection! (I've never been in Verucchio before, good excuse to visit it!)

Comment: @Matte.Car Sorry, actually it was 12.421985055433823. You were off by 0.0000005 mm.